# Will Jesus reveal himeself to anyone with the name "Isa"

Tags: life-of-jesus, prophecy

Last month, I went to a convention where a popular preacher narrated a story(real incident). According to the incident, a muslim youth had a vision in which God Jesus himself revealed to her with the name 'Isa' and asked her to study the pages of Quran.

How could Jesus reveal to anyone by a book which denies Jesus is the God, which also denies that God has died for our sin and many such...?

Comment: I have personally met someone who was Muslim and was studying the Quran.  From that, he learned that Moses received the Law, Mohammed received the Quran, but Jesus received the Spirit of God.  He reasoned that the Spirit of God was a greater thing to receive than the others, so he went in search of Jesus and became a believer.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that he won't reveal himself as "Jesus".  If he does, it will be something like, "I'm the one you call Jesus.  Some of you call me Isa.  Some of you call me Emmanuel.  Some of you call me Yeshua ben Yosef."

Comment: Ultimately, your question is a Truth question and one that cannot be answered because you're talking about an event that hasn't happened yet. [FAQ]

Comment: As the question asks for an interpretation, within Christianity, of a vision that was alleged to have happened, I think it's a good question. Even if I did get tripped up with the dangling modifier in the subject line wording. If you are an "expert" in Christian doctrine, it could seem an insidious question, but the "how could" line implies the questioner finds the event dubious as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true that Acts 4:12 states:

> for there is no other name under heaven given to mankind by which we must be saved."

it is not true that the syllables must be uttered in a particular language.  Unlike, say, the Qu'ran, no mainstream Christian denomination posits the necessity of a particularly holy language.

"Isa" is clearly the identification of the same individual that Christians call Jesus of Nazareth.  It is a peculiarly Islamic name, and the Islamic understanding of who Jesus is differs, but it is the same individual.  To the extent that one believes Isa died on a cross (something that a Qu'ranic interpretation would deny) and that Isa rose again (again, Qu'ranically contradindicated), then Salvation would come through Isa.

It is true that Muslims believe that Isa was a man, but they deny he actually died on the cross. They also deny he was God.  But they do recognize him as a great prophet, teacher, and worker of miracles.  As such, there is a basis on which to build.

Indeed, in the Muslim world. I have heard many reports of Central Asian missionaries retelling the stories of Muslims who have had dreams in which Isa has revealed himself to Muslims.  Key to these dreams, however, is that he is who the Christians say he is - the Son of God who died on the cross and rose again.

The question, thus, is not, what will Jesus' name be in whatever target language, but rather, what attributes does he reveal of himself.  Anecdotally, it is occurring (I wish I could find the movie I saw about this!).  By leveraging what a person knows of Jesus, but correcting the errors, Isa makes the bridge to understanding.

Comment: I read somewhere that for Jews, 'when our messiah comes and brings peace, the difficulty won't be in our acceptance of him, but in convincing the Christians that he's not Jesus.'  Which is completely interesting to me to think about.  Everyone will believe that he's the one that they're waiting for (Muslims, Jews, Christians, etc).  IMHO, they'll all be right - it cannot work any other way.

Comment: @Geek. I was more concerned about my later part of the question. 'Will Jesus asks her to study the pages of Quran' instead of the 'Holy Bible'

Comment: In my experience, the Qu'ran serves the same role for a Muslim that the Torah does for the Jew - it is, as Galatians calls it, a nursemaid whose job it is to bring the Muslim to Christ.  Through it, they are convicted of the law, and their inability to save themselves.  When Jesus appears, he more fully communicates who he is, and then directs them back to the Bible.  As the "People of the Book," Muslims are already open to the Bible, even if they are to taught to believe it less reliable then their Quran.

Answer (score 1):

The bible gives an instance of Jesus revealing himself to a nonbeliever: Saul of Tarsus (Acts 9:4). So it is not outside Jesus's nature to appear to nonbelievers.

To be literal about the word *reveal*, there are many ways that Jesus is revealed besides special apparitions. He reveals himself by the Word (John 1:1). He reveals himself, he appears, through the sacrament of communion (Luke 22:19). He reveals himself through the poor around us who have physical needs (Matt 25:31ff).

But you are correct to doubt that a vision/ apparition would encourage one to believe that Jesus was mere prophet.  1 John 4 (NIV) says:

> Dear friends, do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits to see whether they are from God, because many false prophets have gone out into the world. This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God, but every spirit that does not acknowledge Jesus is not from God. This is the spirit of the antichrist, which you have heard is coming and even now is already in the world.

Comment: I think he means that Jesus will reveal Himself as "Isa"--the name for Him in Arabic.

Comment: @Narnian I was more concerned about my later part of the question. 'Will Jesus asks her to study the pages of Quran' instead of the 'Holy Bible'

Answer (score 1):

> 1Ti 4:1  Now the Spirit speaketh expressly, that in the latter times some shall depart from the faith, giving heed to seducing spirits, and doctrines of devils;
> 1Ti 4:2  Speaking lies in hypocrisy; having their conscience seared with a hot iron;
>
> 2Co 11:14  And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into an angel of light.
>
> Jas 5:14  Is any sick among you? let him call for the elders of the church; and let them pray over him, anointing him with oil in the name of the Lord:

From the Bible literalist perspective having a vision of Jesus and the being in the vision telling you to follow anything other than the word of God would be a doctrine of a devil and a candidate for a work of the devil.

From a Christian Psychologist perspective lots of people who are mentally sick have hallucinations involving religious figures and beings which tell them things from their own mind. This does not mean that all visions or religious experiences are false but it does mean that sometimes highly functional mentally ill people do have religious experiences not supported by the word of God (and sometimes even seemingly supported by the word of God). Its possible to induce a hallucination in an otherwise normal person through certain actions involving drugs and sometimes not involving drugs. Having psychotic episodes in such fashion is very dangerous.